# if else in cakePHP not displaying default image

Tags: php, image, cakephp, file-exists

I'm trying to display a default image in cakePHP when the entry for the file path to the image stored in the DB is empty. What I'm finding is happening with the code below, is that if the DB entry is empty the default image is displayed, but it's also displayed if there is an entry in the DB.

So, for some reason if there is an entry in the DB $image is not being displayed. Appreciate the help.

Paul

```
<?php

$image = $this->Html->image(
        $news['News']['imgPath'],
        array('title' => $news['News']['alt_tag'], 'class' => 'left'),
        array('escape' => false));                 

    $default_image = "<img src=\"/FBCW_new2/files/uploads/default.jpg\" class=\"left\" alt=\"default image\"/>";

    if(file_exists("$image")) $filename = $image;

    else $filename = $default_image;

    echo $filename;
  ?>
```

**Resolution:**
Since $image is an html string, I added a variable to first check if the file path was empty, and then set the $filename by it.

```
        $photo = $news['News']['imgPath'];
        $image = $this->Html->image(
                      $news['News']['imgPath'],
                      array('title' => $news['News']['alt_tag'], 'class' => 'left'),
                      array('escape' => false));                 

      $default_image = "<img src=\"/FBCW_new2/files/uploads/default.jpg\" class=\"left\" alt=\"default image\"/>";

       if(!empty($photo)) $filename = $image;

       else $filename = $default_image;

       echo $filename;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're checking whether `$image` is a valid file path, but `$image` holds an HTML string; therefore, `file_exists` will almost invariably return `false`. You want to check if the file path is valid:

```
if(file_exists(APP . WEBROOT_DIR . '/' . $news['News']['imgPath'])){
     // ...
}
```

Note: Depending on where you're storing these images (and how your storing their file paths), you'll likely need to use the [`APP`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/global-constants-and-functions.html#core-definition-constants) constant (and others) to check the correct absolute file path.

You might want to create a helper that does image-replacement like this for you, see [Helpers - CakePHP Cookbook 2.0](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/helpers.html#creating-helpers).

Comment: Thanks Jacob, I've changed the code to the following, but now the default image is not displaying.     $image = $this->Html->image(
            $news['News']['imgPath'],
            array('title' => $news['News']['alt_tag'], 'class' => 'left'),
            array('escape' => false));                  

    $default_image = "<img src=\"/FBCW_new2/files/uploads/St-Petersburg-2.jpg\" class=\"left\" alt=\"default image\"/>";

       if(file_exists(APP . WEBROOT_DIR . '/' . $news['News']['imgPath'])) $filename = $image;
         
       else $filename = $default_image;

       echo $filename;

Comment: @Paul What shows up instead of the default image? Have you checked the HTML source generated? Can you add brackets around the conditionals?

Comment: for records where there is no filepath in the db, what shows up in the view source is: <img src="/domain/img/" title="" class="left" alt="">. Should the $default_image be formatted differently?

Comment: I've resolved this. By pointing out that $image was an html string helped. I've added the resolution above.